# c program unsigned int or uint8_t

Tags: c, variables, types

I am writing a function called `take_picture()`. The function will make a camera take a picture and store the data in an array.

I want the function to return the address where the array is located and to return the size of the array.

So this is my function declaration:

```
uint8_t * take_picture(int *piclength)
```

My question is what would be the correct/logical data types for the function return type and the argument? considering that they store an address and size of an array? Does a `uint8_t` and `int` make sense?

Thanks

Comment: Try `int size = 0; uint8_t * address = take_picture(& size);`

Comment: If you want to convert a pointer to an integer (why BTW?), its type should be `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There are legitimate cases where this is useful, for example to pass it to a Java class method from and to JNI.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I know there are. Not sure about this specific case.

Comment: Do **not** use casts if you don't understand them. Why don't you use the correct types? Your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Whyever would you intentionally choose to use data types that disagree with the function declaration in the first place?  Casts are occasionally appropriate, but they are far more often a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi - I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: Do you really want an address, or just a pointer to the array contents?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what would be the correct/logical data types for the function return type and the argument? considering that they store an address and size of an array?

The function return type should be a pointer to an array item. If it is an array of `uint8_t`, then the return type should be `uint8_t*`. This is also the most correct/safe type for an array of bytes ("raw data").

The most correct type used to describe the size of an array is `size_t`, an unsigned integer type that exists specifically for this purpose, and is guaranteed portably to be large enough to hold an array size of the given system.

```
uint8_t* take_picture (size_t* piclength);
```

or alternatively

```
void take_picture (uint8_t* picture, size_t* piclength);
```

Comment: I think the 2nd one should take a `uint8_t**` rather than a `uint8_t*` so that `*picture` will point to whatever was allocated.

Comment: @Kevin It isn't obvious what the function does. "The function will make a camera take a picture and store the data in an array" could mean anything. It is best to leave allocation to the caller if that's an option.

Answer (score -1):

unsigned int size; // As the image size is always positive and is large.

uintptr_t address; // if this is available in stdint.h

or

unsigned int address; //it is capable of storing a pointer size.

address = take_picture(&size); //take_picture if returns uintptr_t

If you do not know what take_picture returns, then you cast it like what you have done:

address = (unsigned *int)take_picture(& size);

Comment: *unsigned int address; //it is capable of storing a pointer size.*  No, it is **NOT**.  That *may* work on older architectures.  That will fail on [every common 64-bit architecture currently extant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).  Never try to put a pointer value into an `int`.